# On how to find a random variable corresponding to a probability measure

Tags: probability

Given an integer $n\geq 2$ and Borel probability measures $\rho_{1}$, $\rho_{2}$,,, $\rho_{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, how do I find a probability space and independent random variables $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$, . . . , $X_{n}$, such that every $X_{j}$ has distribution $\rho_{j}$?

I'm considering taking the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ as my probability space. To find the random variables, I'm considering to let $X_{j}$ be any Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. However, I failed to relate my $X_{j}$ to $\rho_{j}$. Should I restrict my $X_{j}$ to some sets measurable to $\rho_{j}$? Or my approach is complete false? Please give me a hint. Thanks!

Comment: We know how to generate independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$. (They can be realized as coordinate functions on the unit cube $[0,1]^n$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure.) The you can transform them to have certain distribution using [*inverse transform sampling*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). A more theoretical but simpler way is to consider the product of probability spaces $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}),\rho_j)$.

Comment: Please don't delete your [old post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003075/question-on-finding-an-appropriate-probability-space-and-random-variables) and post a new one. You are supposed to improve your posts and be patient.

Comment: @Max sorry I won't do that next time.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Thanks for the help. It seems that I'm still having trouble marrying into the notion of "random variable". I tried to have my $X_{j}$ to take on the values of $\rho_{j}^{-1}(y)$. But I can't show this $X_{j}$ is a random variable. Am I on the right direction here?

Comment: I would like to recommend you to review the notion of radnom variable and the distribution of it. A random variable is simply a measurable function. Its notion departs from the usual measure theory and becomes special only when you begin to investigate how it is intertweaved with the probability measure on the domain. Such information is encoded in the notion of distribution.

Comment: As your book should explain, one can choose $$\Omega=\mathbb R^n\qquad\mathcal F=\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)\qquad P=\rho_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\rho_n\qquad X_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_k$$